# Low level react animation API unable to make it work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was doing a bit of animation in my React application. I used `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` to add up the animations on page transition. But now I want to use the low level API `ReactTransitionGroup` but it's not working. I used:

```
import {ReactTransitionGroup} from 'react-addons-transition-group';
```

Then inside class I am rendering:

```
render() {
    const {user} = this.props;
    const styles = require('./App.scss');

    return (
      <div className={styles.app}>
        <ReactTransitionGroup component={React.DOM.html} transitionName="example">
          <div className={styles.appContent}>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </ReactTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
}
```

I am unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am getting this error:

> React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

Please let me know what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **named** ES6 import syntax:

```
import {ReactTransitionGroup} from 'react-addons-transition-group';
```

This is *not* the same as using ES6 **default** import syntax:

```
import ReactTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-transition-group';
```

If you use ES6 modules, it is paramount that you [understand the difference between named and default imports](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). A module can have a single default export and/or many named exports, and there is a big difference between them.

Now, `react-addons-transition-group` is not an ES module. It is a CommonJS package published on npm. The official examples show how to use it in a CommonJS environment:

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');
```

You probably use a transpiler like Babel. In this case it’s important that you understand [how Babel interops with CommonJS modules](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html). CommonJS is not like ES Modules and doesn’t have a concept of named or default exports. This is why **Babel interprets modules written in CommonJS style as having only a single default export, and no named exports.** Of course, ES modules compiled with Babel include special hints so it can recognize them later, but this isn’t the case for `react-addons-css-transition-group` which was originally written in CommonJS style.

This is why

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');
```

corresponds to

```
import ReactTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-transition-group';
```

and not

```
import {ReactTransitionGroup} from 'react-addons-transition-group';
```

Comment: Mine main purpose to use this ReactTransitionGroup was so that i can use the  lifecycle hooks like componentWillEnter(callback),  componentWillLeave(callback). So i wanted to know that can i add these life cycle hooks in mine same class as referenced to the above example. I tried to add it but those life cycle hooks were not being called. So can you let me know a code snippet

Comment: This is a different and unrelated question. Please create a new one, show what you have tried, and what did not work.

Comment: yes i have created a new http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964659/how-to-use-life-cycle-hooks-for-animation-using-react-low-level-api